# Filtering in DIP using Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, digital

I have a CT image of a lung as shown below :

[image]

I am trying to filter the inner of the two lungs such that i only remove the thin lines of the bronchi ,but i need to keep these small "circles " as much as i can for extraction in the next step as these small circles are nodules candidates ( cancerous structures ) . So please if you can mention to me a good filtering technique for this purpose. Thanks in advance

Comment: It would help if you drew on the image what exactly you want to concentrate on.  Honestly when I see your wall of text, I zone out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try imfilter, with Gaussian, or perhaps disk filter. Try:

```
img=imread('orsoR.png');
h = fspecial('disk',5);
y = imfilter(h, img);
figure;
imshow(y)
```

Comment: If you're using `fspecial`, that means you have the image processing toolbox. `imfilter` is a far superior mechanism for filtering images and is part of the toolbox. It's optimised specially for images.